# How to create function based on ggsurvplot?

Tags: survival-analysis

I am trying to create a function that would plot Kaplan-Meyer plots for different events (an event is an argument to a function). This code works perfectly:

```
km_fit <- survfit(Surv(Observation_ControlPeriod, Late_LethalOutcome) ~ MainGroup, data = df.point9.Total_DE)
show(km_fit)
ggsurvplot(km_fit, data = df.point9.Total_DE)
```

But when I try to create something like this:

```
kaplan.meier.plot <- function(t_subset, control.period.label, control.event.label, control.group.label) {
  control.period <- as.numeric(t_subset[[control.period.label]])
  control.event <- as.numeric(t_subset[[control.event.label]])
  control.group <- as.numeric(t_subset[[control.group.label]])

  km_fit <- survfit(
    Surv(
      as.numeric(t_subset[[control.period.label]]),
      as.numeric(t_subset[[control.event.label]]))
    ~ as.numeric(t_subset[[control.group.label]]),
    data = t_subset
  )

  ggsurvplot(km_fit, data = t_subset)
},
```

I get an error "t_subset object not found".

I can't fix it because I think that I don't understand something important in the R functions syntax.